# text and images overlapping- not quite sure what's going on.

Tags: css, wordpress, padding, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm just about done with a redesign of my site, but I've noticed that on my main blog page, the images and text are overlapping. I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using Wordpress- the images in the posts are not 'featured images,' they are instead just embedded within the post. I'd like to have a little bit of space between images at the top of each post and the accompanying text.

Anyway, here's my site- [http://whskytngfxtrt.com/](http://whskytngfxtrt.com)

Also, if I may add a second question here.. I'm hoping to make this fluid, adjusting to individual browser widths. Is it advisable to just replace px with %(and how do I determine px : % ?)? If not, what is the best method?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have more luck here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: will post there, thanks!

Comment: they referred me back here, it seems to have more to do with css than WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#main .post_entry p {margin-top: -82px}` CSS rule you have in your stylesheet makes paragraph tags overlap with other content. I'm not quite sure why that rule exists.

Add `clear:both` and `float:left` to both `.postinfo` and `#headline` to get everything aligned again.

Comment: my intention with having the `#main .post_entry p {margin-top: -82px}` was to bring the post content on the right level with headline/meta on the left. with that rule removed, the content gets shifted back down. how else can i bring it up?

Answer (score 0):

Also, for

> ## sidebar #twitter {margin-top: 20px}

change that to 50px. To fix the overlapping text on right.